# Missing module 'awx.main.db'

Tags: python, kubernetes, ansible-awx

Currently trying to install awx on Kubernetes but any command related to awx-manage fails with `Error was: No module named 'awx.main.db'`. I've tried running these commands manually via -- /bin/bash into the container but get the same error.

These are the  tasks that fail:

```
- name: Migrate database
  shell: |
    {{ kubectl_or_oc }} -n {{ kubernetes_namespace }} exec ansible-tower-management -- \
      bash -c "awx-manage migrate --noinput"

- name: Check for Tower Super users
  shell: |
    {{ kubectl_or_oc }} -n {{ kubernetes_namespace }} exec ansible-tower-management -- \
      bash -c "echo 'from django.contrib.auth.models import User; nsu = User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True).count(); exit(0 if nsu > 0 else 1)' | awx-manage shell"
  register: super_check
  ignore_errors: no
  changed_when: super_check.rc > 0

- name: create django super user if it does not exist
  shell: |
    {{ kubectl_or_oc }} -n {{ kubernetes_namespace }} exec ansible-tower-management -- \
      bash -c "echo \"from django.contrib.auth.models import User; User.objects.create_superuser('{{ admin_user }}', '{{ admin_email }}', '{{ admin_password }}')\" | awx-manage shell"
  no_log: no
  when: super_check.rc > 0

- name: update django super user password
  shell: |
    {{ kubectl_or_oc }} -n {{ kubernetes_namespace }} exec ansible-tower-management -- \
      bash -c "awx-manage update_password --username='{{ admin_user }}' --password='{{ admin_password }}'"
  no_log: no
  register: result
  changed_when: "'Password updated' in result.stdout"
```

Full error from container logs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 115, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'awx.main.db'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/bin/daphne", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(CommandLineInterface.entrypoint())
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/daphne/cli.py", line 144, in entrypoint
    cls().run(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/daphne/cli.py", line 174, in run
    channel_layer = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/awx/asgi.py", line 37, in <module>
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/channels/asgi.py", line 115, in get_channel_layer
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 124, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 134, in load_backend
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'awx.main.db.profiled_pg' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
Error was: No module named 'awx.main.db'
2019-03-20 16:04:31,541 INFO exited: daphne (exit status 1; not expected)
2019-03-20 16:04:32,546 INFO spawned: 'daphne' with pid 2587
2019-03-20 16:04:33,555 INFO success: daphne entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a module for your database backend is missed in your container - `awx.main.db.profiled_pg`. That is pretty new code, but it is not released in stable yet.

That is a know [issue](https://github.com/ansible/awx/issues/3250). Try to follow suggestion from that ticket:

> The solution is to download the tar.gz archive for awx-3.0.1 from the github repo, and use that to deploy, rather than the devel branch.

Comment: Ah, okay. I'll give that a go. Right after i posted this i found https://github.com/ansible/awx/issues/3250 which gives the same suggestion. Thanks.